# How to clone html using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to clone html using AngularJS, I did it by using jQuery but it conflicts with angular so I want make with AngularJS. My code is given below:

```js
function printContent(el){
    var restorepage = $('body').html();
    var printcontent = $('#' + el).clone();
    $('body').empty().html(printcontent);
    window.print(); 
    $('body').html(restorepage);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `JQlite` for this

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
myEl.clone();
```

Remember to put the `jquery` file before the `angular.js` file in the HTML to make use of `JQlite`.

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector('div[ng-app]').innerHTML